# Xamarin.Forms - Binding a command

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using ToolKits Expander and I am trying to bind a command, this is what I got so far:

```
public partial class AssignTaskPage : ContentPage
    {

        

        public AssignTaskPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetMathSubCatgories = new Command(() => MathSubCatgoriesCommand());

        }

        public ICommand GetMathSubCatgories { get; private set; }
        void MathSubCatgoriesCommand()
        {
            Console.Write("Here");
        }

    }
```

And in my view

```
<xct:Expander Command="{Binding GetMathSubCatgories}">
                            <xct:Expander.Header>
                                <Frame Padding="10" Margin="10" HasShadow="False" BorderColor="LightGray" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding icon}" WidthRequest="25" HeightRequest="25"></Image>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="{Binding textColor}" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </Frame>
                            </xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ListView x:Name="SubCategories" ItemsSource="{Binding subCategories}" ItemSelected="SubCategories_ItemSelected">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <ViewCell>
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding name}" TextColor="#02cc9d" FontAttributes="Bold" HeightRequest="35" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </ViewCell>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Grid>
                        </xct:Expander>
```

This does not work at all, (I put a break point on Console.Write("Here"); and its not hitting it)

So I did some digging and found this tutorial:

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12154/how-to-bind-command-to-expander-in-itemtemplate-of-xamarin-forms-listview-sflistview

and here is the sample in git.

https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/command-to-expander-in-itemtemplate-listview-xamarin

I understand what I have to do here, the problem I am facing is when this Command is called, I was looking to get a value and use it in my AssignTaskPage, but what the tutorial is saying to have a ViewModel which is in a separate file. So should I setup a MessagingCenter in my AssignTaskPage and call it in the ViewModel to get the value I want and pass it to AssignTaskPage?

Comment: Yes, bindings are based on MVVM pattern, you need a ViewModel so that your binding works, you need to assign your bindingcontext of your xaml to that new class(ViewModel) which you create(where the command will be called) and not codebehind file.

Comment: Okay, I’m planning on adding a parameter for the binding, how would I get that parameter back to AssignTaskPage? MessagingCenter?

Comment: It's a good idea to do it in viewmodel and not in your codebehind check how command parameters are used here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding  also if you want something in your viewmodel to change your view you need two way binding the default is one way.

Answer (score 0):

Because your command isn't defined in the ViewModel that you're binding to.You could bind the command which is defined in your `AssignTaskPage`,and then bind the viewmodel for the parent element of the expander.

For example :

```
public partial class AssignTaskPage : ContentPage
{

    public AssignTaskPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetMathSubCatgories = new Command(() => MathSubCatgoriesCommand());
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public ICommand GetMathSubCatgories { get; private set; }
    void MathSubCatgoriesCommand(object obj)
    {
          DisplayAlert("Alert!", "" + (obj as Contact).ContactName + "expanded", "Ok");
    }

}
```

the xaml (here use the xaml codes of the above sample),the grid bind the viewmodel,and your expander bind the command of the root (your page):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ExpanderXamarin"
         x:Class="ExpanderXamarin.ExpandableListView"
         x:Name="root"
         xmlns:sflistview="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.ListView.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfListView.XForms"
         xmlns:expander="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.Expander;assembly=Syncfusion.Expander.XForms">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" BackgroundColor="#F0F0F0" Padding="4">
        <Grid.BindingContext>
            <local:ViewModel />
        </Grid.BindingContext>
        <sflistview:SfListView x:Name="listView" AutoFitMode="DynamicHeight" ItemsSource="{Binding ContactsInfo}">
            <sflistview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Frame x:Name="frame" CornerRadius="2" Padding="{OnPlatform Android=1, iOS=1,  UWP=0}" Margin="{OnPlatform Android=1, iOS=1,  UWP=0}" OutlineColor="White" HasShadow="{OnPlatform Android=true, iOS=false, UWP=true}">
                        <Grid Padding="{OnPlatform Android=2, iOS=2,  UWP=0}" Margin="{OnPlatform Android=1, iOS=1,  UWP=0}" BackgroundColor="White" >
                            <expander:SfExpander x:Name="expander"   HeaderIconPosition="None">
                                <expander:SfExpander.Behaviors>
                                    <local:EventToCommandBehavior Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.GetMathSubCatgories, Source={x:Reference root}}" EventName="Expanding" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                                </expander:SfExpander.Behaviors>
                                <expander:SfExpander.Header>
                                   ...
                                </expander:SfExpander.Header>
                                <expander:SfExpander.Content>
                                   ..
                                </expander:SfExpander.Content>
                            </expander:SfExpander>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sflistview:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
        </sflistview:SfListView>
    </Grid>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

if you want get the parameters you could bind the `CommandParameter` like above.